# What's the best way to show multiple options for opening a codebase?

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks, command-line, code, many-options

I'd like to give users of a desktop app I'm working on the option of accessing their local code either through the Windows Explorer/Mac Finder or through the command-line, what's the best way to do this? I also want to display the local file path to their code directory.

Something like this but I think it looks kinda bad right now
[image: access local code]

Comment: Without any context like who is going to use this, why and when, this is more a graphic design question than UX. Can you add some user stories or wireframes that give a broader view?

Comment: Hm yea in retrospect this may not be the most ux-related question

This is for a program that lets users host local websites on a remote server and they need to be able to both open their local codebase via whatever file directory its in, and to open it through a command line program

Does that help?

Comment: WIll most power-users that want a console not simply make an FTP connection to the server instead? Where as the average-joes in the world would probably be better off with some wordpress kinda thing?

Comment: Offering a FTP connection to the server is a possible action as well (just not shown in this screenshot. I believe the 'average-joes' of our product have some level of coding experience, so they can open up whatever files they need through the Explorer/Finder.

Comment: It seems good this way, why do you think its bad?

Answer (score 1):

SourceTree has a great example of the workflow you're mentioning. I'm not sure of the use case for your specific example, but in SourceTree, 95% of the time you're just looking to open the repository.

[image]

As a result, SourceTree has created a **default action** of clicking on the item in the list to open the list, and has buried other actions under the right-click context menu.

[image: Box.com more options menu]

If you want to provide access to some other actions without using Right-Click, a "more options" button at the end could also work well. Box.com has an excellent example of the default action being to open, the first **promoted** action is to share and then all the other options are in the overflow.

In your example, I would recommend determining which one of the actions is the primary action, and then burying the other action in a Right-Click context menu (as you have said, this is a desktop app and right click is available).